# How can I view Youtube videos in Tor browser?

Tags: browser, youtube, tor

For some reason I'm unable to view videos on Youtube when using the Tor browser. What steps do I have to take to view them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Tor Browser will block browser plugins such as Flash, RealPlayer, Quicktime, and others. Those plugins can be manipulated into revealing your real IP address and harming your anonymity and privacy. Therefore, it's not recommended to install additional addons or plugins into the Tor Browser.

The lack of plugins means that Youtube videos are not available by default, but Youtube does provide an experimental HTML5-player as an opt-in feature that works for most videos. Follow [this link](https://www.youtube.com/html5) to enable this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is a firefox addon called 'cocoon' which works the same as tor browser. After installing this, you can watch youtube videos as well.